# Unzip a file from network

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, desktop-application, unzip, winzip

I'am trying to unzip a file from netowrk in C# with this syntax:

```
string dezarhiverPath = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["PathWinZip"] + "\\WINZIP32.EXE";
ProcessStartInfo pro = new ProcessStartInfo();
pro.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
pro.FileName = dezarhiverPath;
pro.Arguments = " -e -j -o " + prmSource + " " + prmDestination;
Process x = Process.Start(pro);
x.WaitForExit();
```

If I use this sintax and my zip file is on local on my computer it works bbut when I move the path and i'am trying to unzip from a location on network doesn't work.Remain at line "x.WaitForExit()".If I try manualy to unzip it works.My user has rights to this location.I don't have error.

Can somebody help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Can somebody tell me what  means the  arguments -e -j -o?

Comment: Set the `WindowStyle` to `Normal` and take a look into the window what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Use external tool for unzipping like [SharpZipLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/) because this way, you dont need to be depend of external tools like winzip.

**Or even better** : with .net 4.5 use System.IO.Compression.ZipFile, this is in assembly  `System.IO.Compression.FileSystem`

For examples see MSDN site  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404280(v=vs.110).aspx